# Sum of factors of a number prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, puzzle, factoring

Could you help me with this problem?

The sum of the positive factors of some positive integer $N$ is $96$. The sum of the positive factors of $N-1$ is $N$. What is the sum of the positive factors of $N+1$?

Note: As $N-1 + 1 = N$ , we have that $N-1$ is a prime number. $42=2*3*7$ seems to be a solution, but I'm not sure if it's unique.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You've already deduced that $N-1$ is prime. Next it's worth noting that the sum of all positive factors of $N$ is at least as big as $N$ itself, so $N\leq96$. This leaves only finitely many cases to check, which is quite doable.

The solution is not unique; the sum of the positive factors of $N+1$ could be either $44$ or $104$. Or $42$ if you allow $N$ to be negative.

Comment: How you find 104 ?

Comment: $1+3+7+9+21+63=104$.

Comment: More constructively, I used the fact that if $N=\prod p_i^{n_i}$ with $p_i$ distinct primes and $n_i$ positive integers, then the divisor sum of $N$ equals
$$\prod\frac{p_i^{n_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}.$$
For this to equal $96=2^5\times3$, there is a unique index $j$ such that $p_j^{n_j+1}=1+2^{m_j}\times3$ for some nonnegative integer $m_j$, and a quick check shows that then $n_j=1$ and $p_j\in\{2,5,7\}$. This leaves very few options for the other primes dividing $N$.